# Make hAxis label center with respect to graph in React-google-charts (React Js)

Tags: reactjs, google-visualization, react-google-charts

I need to have centered data points in hAxis(x-axis) with respect to vAxis(y-axis), I tried with textPosition and but it doesn't work.
[image]

Here, I have to center the dates with respect to the graph.

Thanks for your minute for me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found the cause by myself. It's because we have date we are using, For the date we have structure (2023, 05, 09) YYYY, MM, DD. If this structure varies while sending the date type. This issue comes.